# How do you fix: "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'events' referenced before assignment" in pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pycharm

I am making a button on my credits screen to go back to the start screen when pressed. I have a button function with 'events' as a parameter, but when I use it on my credits scene. However, this error occurs: "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'events' referenced before assignment". I don't understand, 'events' isn't even a variable. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
  File "/Users/qingduliu/PycharmProjects/Pygame3/Shoot 'em Up.py", line 355, in credits
button(events, 10, 10, 120, 60, WHITE, GRAY, 'back')
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'events' referenced before assignment
```

Code

```
def button(events, x, y, width, height, ic, ac, action=None):

    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    # print(mouse)

    if x + width > mouse[0] > x and y + height > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, ac, (x, y, width, height), 0)
        if events.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and action is not None:
            if action == 'play':
                game_loop()
            elif action == 'credits':
                credits()
            elif action == 'instructions':
                instructions()
            elif action == 'back':
                start_screen()
            elif action == 'quit':
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, ic, (x, y, width, height), 0)


def start_screen():

    start = True

    while start:

        clock.tick(FPS)
        for events in pygame.event.get():
            if events.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        screen.blit(background, background_rect)
        pygame.transform.scale(player_img, (50, 38))
        player_img.set_colorkey(BLACK)
        screen.blit(player_img, (10, HEIGHT - 120))
        screen.blit(player_img, (WIDTH - 110, HEIGHT - 120))
        bullet_img.set_colorkey(BLACK)
        screen.blit(bullet_img, (55, 400))
        screen.blit(bullet_img, (415, 400))
        screen_meteor.set_colorkey(BLACK)
        screen.blit(screen_meteor, (5, 220))
        screen.blit(screen_meteor, (WIDTH - 105, 220))
        boss_img.set_colorkey(BLACK)
        pygame.transform.scale(boss_img, (50, 38))
        screen.blit(boss_img, (190, 25))

        button(events, 180, 285, 120, 60, BLUE, LIGHT_BLUE, 'play')
        button(events, 202, HEIGHT - 150, 80, 40, WHITE, GRAY, 'quit')
        button(events, 310, 45, 140, 30, WHITE, GRAY, 'credits')
        button(events, 20, 45, 140, 30, WHITE, GRAY, 'instructions')

        draw_text(screen, "Shoot 'Em Up", 80, WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 4, WHITE)
        draw_text(screen, "Instructions", 30, 90, 53, BLACK)
        draw_text(screen, "Credits", 35, 378, 50, BLACK)
        draw_text(screen, "Play", 55, WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2, WHITE)
        draw_text(screen, "Quit", 30, WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT - 137, BLUE)

        pygame.display.flip()


def credits():

    credits = True

    while credits:

        clock.tick(FPS)
        for events in pygame.event.get():
            if events.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        screen.blit(background, background_rect)
        draw_text(screen, "Credits", 100, WIDTH / 2, 15, WHITE)
        draw_text(screen, "Game Template:", 60, WIDTH / 2, 95, WHITE)
        draw_text(screen, "Kids Can Code, Shmup, Chris Bradfield", 35, WIDTH / 2, 155, WHITE)
        draw_text(screen, "Youtube Channel", 30, WIDTH / 2, 195, WHITE)
        draw_text(screen, "https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCNaPQ5uLX5iIEHUCLmfAgKg", 20, WIDTH / 2, 220, WHITE)
        draw_text(screen, "Blog", 30, WIDTH / 2, 245, WHITE)
        draw_text(screen, "http://kidscancode.org/blog/tags/pygame/", 20, WIDTH / 2, 270, WHITE)
        draw_text(screen, "Music:", 60, WIDTH / 2, 300, WHITE)
        draw_text(screen, "Frozen Jam by tgfcoder", 45, WIDTH / 2, 345, WHITE)
        draw_text(screen, "Twitter", 30, WIDTH / 2, 380, WHITE)
        draw_text(screen, "<https://twitter.com/tgfcoder>", 20, WIDTH / 2, 403, WHITE)
        draw_text(screen, "licensed under CC-BY-3 <http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/>", 15, WIDTH / 2, 425, WHITE)
        draw_text(screen, "Art:", 60, WIDTH / 2, 450, WHITE)
        draw_text(screen, "Kenney.nl", 35, WIDTH / 2, 490, WHITE)
        draw_text(screen, "https://opengameart.org/", 20, WIDTH / 2, 520, WHITE)
        draw_text(screen, "Background https://imgur.com/bHiPMju by Chris Bradfield", 20, WIDTH / 2, 540, WHITE)
        draw_text(screen, "Thank You for all your help and hard work!", 32, WIDTH / 2, 560, RED)

        button(events, 10, 10, 120, 60, WHITE, GRAY, 'back')
        draw_text(screen, "Back", 25, 13, 13, WHITE)

        pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: you should use `button` inside loop `for events` because it has to run with every event.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: normally you should add bigger indention and move to `for`- loop. But you use this weird button from some tutorial which checks collision and draws in the same code so you have to move `for`-loop in different place

Comment: Yeah I know that's kind of inefficient.

Comment: Not to bother you, but do you mind helping with my other questions below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 button(events, 180, 285, 120, 60, BLUE, LIGHT_BLUE, 'play')
```

In your first code block you reference events outside of the `for` loop which defines the `events` variable

Comment: I did it was already in my game_loop():                    
events = pygame.event.get()

Comment: Corrected answer

Comment: Going to the credit screen works, but when I put a button on the credit screen, the error occurs

Comment: @ Jammy Dodger defines the what?

Comment: Corrected the answer

Comment: So what should I do instead?

Comment: Do the `for events` loop inside of button, rather than passing it as a variable

Comment: rather use `button` inside `for events`

Comment: However, now I can't see the buttons themselves, just the text. Can you guys fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You have to move buttons to events loop because buttons have to check every event.

Because you use function which check collision with mouse and draw button in one code so you have to move event loop to buttons.

```
    clock.tick(FPS)

    # - draw background, etc. -

    screen.blit(background, background_rect)
    pygame.transform.scale(player_img, (50, 38))
    player_img.set_colorkey(BLACK)
    screen.blit(player_img, (10, HEIGHT - 120))
    screen.blit(player_img, (WIDTH - 110, HEIGHT - 120))
    bullet_img.set_colorkey(BLACK)
    screen.blit(bullet_img, (55, 400))
    screen.blit(bullet_img, (415, 400))
    screen_meteor.set_colorkey(BLACK)
    screen.blit(screen_meteor, (5, 220))
    screen.blit(screen_meteor, (WIDTH - 105, 220))
    boss_img.set_colorkey(BLACK)
    pygame.transform.scale(boss_img, (50, 38))
    screen.blit(boss_img, (190, 25))

    # - buttons - events + draw  -

    for events in pygame.event.get():
        if events.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

        button(events, 180, 285, 120, 60, BLUE, LIGHT_BLUE, 'play')
        button(events, 202, HEIGHT - 150, 80, 40, WHITE, GRAY, 'quit')
        button(events, 310, 45, 140, 30, WHITE, GRAY, 'credits')
        button(events, 20, 45, 140, 30, WHITE, GRAY, 'instructions')

    # - draw text on buttons -

    draw_text(screen, "Shoot 'Em Up", 80, WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 4, WHITE)
    draw_text(screen, "Instructions", 30, 90, 53, BLACK)
    draw_text(screen, "Credits", 35, 378, 50, BLACK)
    draw_text(screen, "Play", 55, WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2, WHITE)
    draw_text(screen, "Quit", 30, WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT - 137, BLUE)

    # - send all on screen -

    pygame.display.flip()
```

Code is weird because now it draws buttons many times - for every event. But to change it you would have to split button into two functions or create class Button with two functions - `draw()` and `handle_event()`

---

**EDIT:** you could try `click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()` and `lick[0] == 1` instead of `events` so it doesn't have to be in `for events` loop but it can make problem when you remove button and put new one in the same place. Python will do it so fast that you will still keep button pressed and python will think that you pressed new button.

```
def button(x, y, width, height, ic, ac, action=None):

    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    # print(mouse)

    if x + width > mouse[0] > x and y + height > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, ac, (x, y, width, height), 0)
        if click[0] == 1 and action is not None:
            if action == 'play':
                game_loop()
            elif action == 'credits':
                credits()
            elif action == 'instructions':
                instructions()
            elif action == 'back':
                start_screen()
            elif action == 'quit':
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, ic, (x, y, width, height), 0)
```

You can assign to `action` function's name instead of text '"credits"`,`"instruction"`ect. and then you can run it as`action()`

```
def button(x, y, width, height, ic, ac, action=None):

    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    # print(mouse)

    if x + width > mouse[0] > x and y + height > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, ac, (x, y, width, height), 0)
        if click[0] == 1 and action is not None:
            action()
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, ic, (x, y, width, height), 0)


button(180, 285, 120, 60, BLUE, LIGHT_BLUE, game_loop)
button(310, 45, 140, 30, WHITE, GRAY, credits)
button(20, 45, 140, 30, WHITE, GRAY, instructions)

button(202, HEIGHT - 150, 80, 40, WHITE, GRAY, game_quit)

def game_quit():
    pygame.quit()
    quit()

button(..., start_screen)
```

Comment: I did that but my designs for the buttons aren't working

Comment: problem is that all code in button is wrong. And it only makes problems. It should be splitted in two functions - `draw()` and `handle_event()` - or better create class `Button` to keep it all together. And then button could even draw text instead of using separated function `draw_text()`

Comment: boundaries seems OK. You can write it using `<` instead or `>` and it should be easier to understand `(x < mouse[0] < x+ width)  and (height < mouse[1] < y + height)`. If you would keep button position and size in `pygame.Rect` then you could check `if button_rect.collidepoitn(mouse) and action is not None:`

Comment: I was thinking about using `click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()` instead of `events` but it makes problem when you change button and new one is in the same place - system think that you clicked new button.

Comment: example which uses class Button - [button-hover](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/pygame/button-hover/example-1.py). Example which keep button's parameters as list and uses functions - `button_create()`, `button_check()`, `button_draw()`, [button-using-function](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/pygame/button-using-function/main.py)

Comment: I added to answer code with `click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()`. It may resolve problem but sometimes it can make other problem.

Comment: I have a question about the button class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197465/discussion-between-blazian444-and-furas).